# Magento - language of some parts of admin section seems to be changed?

Tags: admin, php, language

I have also posted on Stackoverflow but didn't get any help as this is bit odd and tricky..

I am having little problem but not so serious yet weird. And I'm checking with my hosting company if there's any security breach was made.

Some parts in admin page, like date on the top section, and options in some places, have what appears to be Filipino language.

Been setup for English user and nobody changed language setting ever since, and I may have some idea if the entire language was changed but not this?

Look at the date, it's obviously not an English.

[image]

And this is the "Locale Options" - "General" in the Admin

[image]

Time zone is set to Australia, but in these drop down and selectable option show different language.

I have mirroring site for test extension and stuff and it shows all English.

I have checked header.phtml in page-template-default-default-adminhtml-design-app and doesn't seem to be edited or nothing indicate about language.

I also checked every places in admin section but I didn't think anything in the backend can allow us to do this weird change.

Wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem before and know how to resolve this?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mas. Have you found the solution to this?

Comment: Yes. Tried that solution below. It was just the dropdown menu on the bottom of the admin section.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunetly it doesn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this content is in 'lib/Zend/Locale/data/fil.xml', so I think you have Interface Locale in Filipino language. You can find Interface Locale section in Magento Admin, just on the bottom left corner if you go to System->Configuration. You just have to change it to English or whatever language you want.
[image]

Comment: Yes I know there's place we can change language on the bottom of the admin section just the image you showed but it's set for English. and In Configuration section, as I said in my question, it's been setup for English. And "fil.xml" file you mentioned above, what exactly do I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: And you didn't change xml files? Maybe you should search through all files in your Magento for a word 'Huwebes' and you will see where this word is in files.

Comment: No I didn't even touch that file. but thanks, and you may be right. Just realized that every time I login to admin, starts with Filipino, then I had to change it to English. never happened before. At least I know where to change..

Comment: Maybe that can help you - how to change the default Magento Admin language and save the selection: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_BackendDefaultLanguage - I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088830/is-it-possible-to-change-magento-backend-language-for-one-user-only.

Comment: Hello I'm filipino. I find it very weird having a filipino language in some part of your magento admin. Did you try using incogto?